# Transferring 1-2 megabytes of data through regular files in Windows - is it slower than through RAM?

Tags: windows, performance, io, hard-drive

I'm passing 1-2 MB of data from one process to another, using a plain old file. Is it significantly slower than going through RAM entirely?

Before answering yes, please keep in mind that in modern Linux at least, when writing a file it is actually written to RAM, and then a daemon syncs the data to disk from time to time. So in that way, if process A writes a 1-2 MB into a file, then process B reads them within 1-2 seconds, process B would simply read the cached memory. It gets even better than that, because in Linux, there is a grace period of a few seconds before a new file is written to the hard disk, so if the file is deleted, it's not written at all to the hard disk. This makes passing data through files as fast as passing them through RAM.

Now that is Linux, is it so in Windows?

**Edit:** Just to lay out some assumptions:

1. The OS is reasonably new - Windows XP or newer for desktops, Windows Server 2003 or newer for servers.
2. The file is significantly smaller than available RAM - let's say less than 1% of available RAM.
3. The file is read and deleted a few seconds after it has been written.

Comment: It has to depend on your configuration. Perhaps, you could try both and compare the results?

Comment: What do you mean by configuration? Do you mean the hardware configuration? I don't see how it would matter, frankly. Or simply the OS version? For OS version - anything NT-based, let's say XP or newer, and Server 2003 or newer for servers.

Comment: Everything matters, in fact. This is why I'm stuck on this site for so long − problems appear in places you wouldn't think they could. For your question, you might get a theoretical answer, but the reality may be different. Only way to know for sure is to try out yourself. By the way, that's kind of a prerequisite for asking a good question on SE. Unless your interest is purely theoretical.

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand that. Do you mean that the hardware configuration affects Windows' caching behavior? In what ways does it affect it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read or write to a file Windows will often keep some or all of the file resident in memory (in the Standby List). So that if it is needed again, it is just a soft-page fault to map it into the processes' memory space.

The algorithm for what pages of a file will be kept around (and for how long) isn't publicly documented. So the short answer is that if you are lucky some or all of it may still be in memory. You can use the SysInternals tool [VMmap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) to see what of your file is still in memory during testing.

If you want to increase your chances of the data remaining resident, then you should use [Memory Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) to pass the data between the two processes.

Good reading on Windows memory management:
[Mysteries of Windows Memory Management Revealed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2010/10/29/pdc10-mysteries-of-windows-memory-management-revealed-part-two.aspx)

Comment: Just to point out 2 things that narrow the scope - the files are assumed to be significantly smaller than available RAM - 1-2 MB, and we assume they are read immediately, or at most 1-2 seconds after they've been written.

Comment: @sashoalm, is the first process still running when the second starts to read the file?

Comment: In my case, it is. Does that affect the caching behavior?

Comment: @sashoalm, If both processes are running at the same time, then memory mapped files become a lot more useful, as you have a better chance of ensuring the entire file remains resident.

Comment: "Better chance" - so even then it's not 100% sure? How much better is the chance that no disk accesses are used? Is it even certain that it's a better chance? From reading that docs, it seems that the probability of having actual disk accesses is unknown in all cases - for regular, temporary and memory-mapped files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to hint that this data is never needed on disk:

> A file that is being used for temporary storage. File systems avoid writing data back to mass storage if sufficient cache memory is available, because typically, an application deletes a temporary file after the handle is closed. In that scenario, the system can entirely avoid writing the data. Otherwise, the data is written after the handle is closed.

(i.e. you need use that flag with CreateFile, and DeleteFile immediately after closing that handle).

---

But even if the file remains cached, you still have to copy it twice: from your process A to the cache (the WriteFile call), and from cache to the proces B (ReadFile call).

Using memory mapped files (MMF, as josh poley already suggested) has the primary advantage of avoiding one copy: the same physical memory pages are mapped into both processes.

A MMF can be backed by virtual memory, which means basically that it always stays in memory unless swapping becomes necessary.

The major downside is that you can't easily grow the memory mapping to changing demands, you are stuck with the initial size.

---

Whether that matters for an 1-2 MB data transfer depends mostly on how you acquire and what you do with the data, in many scenarios the additional copy doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't asking for advice about what I should do. I was asking about Windows' caching behavior. It's a concrete, theoretical question. "But even if the file remains cached, you still have to copy it twice" - sorry, I wasn't clear, I meant **significantly slower**, i.e. would it be 100-200 times slower because process B has to read the data from disk storage instead of RAM.

Comment: @sashoalm: See the MSDN quote regarding FILE_FLAG_TEMPORARY: ** File systems avoid writing data back to mass storage if sufficient cache memory is available** - so no, usually no disk write.